# How to get content of CDATA section (and strip all HTML tags from it)

Tags: org-mode, xml

I am trying to parse an RSS feed element returned by `org-feed-parse-rss-feed` with a custom version of [org-feed-parse-rss-entry](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-feed.el#n641).

```lisp
(defun aleneum/org-feed-parse-rss-entry (entry)
  "Parse the `:item-full-text' field for xml tags and create new properties."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (plist-get entry :item-full-text))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "<\\([a-zA-Z]+\\>\\).*?>\\([^\000]*?\\)</\\1>"
                  nil t)
      (setq entry (plist-put entry
                 (intern (concat ":" (match-string 1)))
                 (xml-substitute-special (match-string 2)))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (unless (re-search-forward "isPermaLink[ \t]*=[ \t]*\"false\"" nil t)
      (setq entry (plist-put entry :guid-permalink t)))
    (setq entry (plist-put entry :title (concat "TODO " (plist-get entry :title))))
    )
  entry)
```

Currently, my addition is rather small and only adds `TODO` to each RSS entry. My problem is that basically all the content in the parsed RSS feed is HTML and wrapped into `CDATA` sections. Parsed entries look like this:

```
* TODO <![CDATA[A title]]>
  2022-04-25 Mon 02:26
  <![CDATA[<p>A paragraph</p>
This is the <pre>HTML</pre> content of this rss entry.
]]>
```

How can I convert this to 'plain' text? Or more precisely: How can I get rid of the `CDATA` annotation and also strip HTML tags from the content?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me (as of now). My goal was to convert RSS entries of a Github issue feed (provided by https://rsshub.app) into TODO items. First, I extended the regular expression that converts tags into ':param'/content pairs to strip `CDATA` prefixes and suffixes and feed the content of `:description` to a pandoc helper function found [here](https://github.com/zonuexe/pandoc.el/blob/master/pandoc.el#L99) to convert the HTML content into org-mode notation:

```lisp
(defun pandoc-convert-stdio (body input-format output-format)
  "Convert `BODY' as `INPUT-FORMAT' to `OUTPUT-FORMAT'."
  (let ((args (list "-f" input-format "-t" output-format)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert body)
      (apply 'call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "pandoc" t t nil args)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))


(defun aleneum/org-feed-parse-github-entry (entry)
  "Parse the `:item-full-text' field for xml tags and create new properties."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (plist-get entry :item-full-text))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "<\\([a-zA-Z]+\\>\\).*?>\\(<!\\[CDATA\\[\\)?\\([^\000]*?\\)\\(\\]\\]>\\)?</\\1>"
                  nil t)
      (setq entry (plist-put entry
                 (intern (concat ":" (match-string 1)))
                 (xml-substitute-special (match-string 3)))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (unless (re-search-forward "isPermaLink[ \t]*=[ \t]*\"false\"" nil t)
      (setq entry (plist-put entry :guid-permalink t)))
    (setq entry (plist-put entry :title (concat "TODO " (plist-get entry :title))))
    (setq entry (plist-put entry :description (pandoc-convert-stdio (plist-get entry :description) "html" "org")))
    )
  entry)
```

I know there are at least two packages (org-sync, org-github-issues) to communicate with Github via their API but since I already consume Gitlab issues via RSS I wanted to keep the general procedure comparable.